# Evitar hacer doble clics en un checklist con Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, font-awesome

Actualmente tuve un problema con una librería que no reconocía el checklist y no tuve otra mas que hacer un propio checklist

Tengo una lista dentro de una tabla así:

```
<td><span class="checked fa fa-square-o"></span> lista 1</td>
<td><span class="checked fa fa-square-o"></span> lista 2</td>
<td><span class="checked fa fa-square-o"></span> lista 3</td>
<td><span class="checked fa fa-square-o"></span> lista 4</td>
<td><span class="checked fa fa-square-o"></span> lista 5</td>
```

Eso muestra un checklist no marcado pero esta con una fuente ( font awesome 4 ) y en el javascript hago lo siguiente usando jQuery:

```
var i = 0;
$(".checked").click(function(){
  if(i==0){
    $(this).addClass('fa-check-square-o');
    $(this).removeClass('fa-square-o');
    i++
  }else{
    $(this).addClass('fa-square-o');
    $(this).removeClass('fa-check-square-o');
    i=0;
  }
});
```

Funciona bien para el primero, pero sucede es que si marco el primero y luego quiero marcar el segundo tengo que hacer doble click para que se marque y así con el siguiente y el siguiente. ¿Hay manera de que no ocurra esto?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es tu variable i.
Intenta verificar primero la clase del span, y de acuerdo a su valor, cambiarlo:

```
$(".checked").click(function(){
  if($(this).hasClass('fa-square-o')){
    $(this).removeClass('fa-square-o');
    $(this).addClass('fa-check-square-o');
  }else{
    $(this).removeClass('fa-check-square-o');
    $(this).addClass('fa-square-o');
  }
});
```